# Filter data frame by choosing most recent one in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame as shown below

```
ID              Date                   Total_Runs 
Sachin       2010-01-06 09:00:00       6000
Sachin       2016-01-06 09:00:00       15000
Kohli        2019-01-06 09:00:00       11000
Kohli        2019-01-06 11:00:00       11060
Devillers    2015-01-06 09:00:00       10000
Devillers    2014-01-06 09:00:00       8000
Devillers    2012-01-06 09:00:00       8000
Devillers    2016-01-06 09:00:00       9000
```

I would like to filter above data frame by selecting most recent runs for each ID (in pandas).

Expected Output:

```
ID              Date                   Total_Runs 
Sachin       2016-01-06 09:00:00       15000
Kohli        2019-01-06 11:00:00       11060
Devillers    2016-01-06 09:00:00       9000
```

Comment: Use `df = df.loc[df.groupby(''ID)['Date'].idxmax()]`

Comment: @jezrael not the max value.. recent value

Comment: Yes, max date is most recent valiue

Comment: @jezrael oh Agreed. Just changed the examples